# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch_scope'

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch, conda

Using the macOS terminal, I'm trying to run `./autoner_train.sh` by following [this guide](https://github.com/shangjingbo1226/AutoNER#command) on GitHub.

I have activated my `Conda` environment and check my `PyTorch` version

```
(pytorch_env) myname (master) AutoNER $ python -c "import torch; print(torch.__version__)"
1.3.1
```

After that, when running, I get the following error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch_scope'

I don't know where's the problem. I have installed everything and I tried googling the problem, all I found is that I need `PyTorch` installed, which I already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I the documentation at the [Dependencies](https://github.com/shangjingbo1226/AutoNER#dependencies) section you can read:

> **Dependencies**
>
> This project is based on `python>=3.6`. The dependent package for this
>   project is listed as below:
>
> `numpy==1.13.1 
>   tqdm 
>   torch-scope>=0.5.0 
>   pytorch==0.4.1`

So you need to install `torch-scope>=0.5.0` too:

```
pip install torch-scope
```